# Keep only text between [] in powershell

Tags: string, powershell

I have a lot of strings from which i only want to keep the text between the `[]`

Example : `/site/GD/[A33.4]Admin, /site/HD/[D9.1]Communication`

I've tried with Regex but didn't find a solution that worked!

```
$pattern = '(?<=\[])\S{3,5}(?=[-\)])'

$results = switch -Regex ($FileDirRef) {
    $pattern {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            String = $_
            Match  = $Matches[0]
        }
    }
    Default { }
}
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

The following should work using [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7.3) to read your file:

```bash
Select-String -LiteralPath $FileDirRef -Pattern '(?<=\[)[^]]+' |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value }
```

Using the sample provided in question would output `A33.4` and `D9.1`:

```bash
'/site/GD/[A33.4]Admin', '/site/HD/[D9.1]Communication' |
    Select-String -Pattern '(?<=\[)[^]]+' |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value }
```

Considering some paths could have more than one group of brackets and you need to capture all strings in between, you should include `-AllMatches`, i.e.:

```bash
'/site/HD/[D9.1]Communication[foo]bar[baz]' |
    Select-String -Pattern '(?<=\[)[^]]+' -AllMatches |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value }
```